# Handle two application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift

I have 2 SDK's that needs to use the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` method. One is `FacebookSDK` and the second is `GooglePlusSDK`.

Those are the methods:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

My question is how is it possible to migrate them into one method? What is the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not determine based on the url based in using a simple `if statement`? Will the URL schemes not be different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could probably do like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL shouldOpen = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    shouldOpen = shouldOpen ? shouldOpen : [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

    return shouldOpen;
}
```

Comment: Thank u. You save my time. Blessings.

Comment: shouldOpen |= [GPPURLHandler handle..]

Answer (score 22):

Use logical OR operator `||`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication] || [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

---

Swift Version

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) || GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner way (here in Swift) would be:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    var handled: Bool
    if let facebook = url.scheme?.hasPrefix("fb") {
        handled = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
    } else {
        handled = GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
    // include any specific handling code as necessary
    return handled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also put the check on the basis prefix of `URL`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString  *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
if FB URL prefix
//Call FB method
else 
//Google plus method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application //facebook & Google+
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return( [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation]
           ||

           [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation]
           );

    ;
}
```